# Class reloading leak on tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc, memory-leaks

I take the following steps:

1. Create simplest servlet and force several times to reload (by modify) tomcat app, to make sure it's not tomcat realated.
2. Add jars to WEB-INF/lib (spring, db2 driver, tomcat-jdbc, hibernate) to make sure that some of classes do not create singletons which are pain if we speak about realoading.

But in both case number of loaded classes where rather stable it's vary, but haven't seen anything abnormal.

So then I tried to register Spring, and DataSource + Hibernate config files. Here's what happening after several reloads:

[image]

Here goes my web.xml & mvc-spring.xml which seems to create this class leak:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.spring" />

    <!-- Required for MVC Spring to use annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- JDBC Connection -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- Credentials -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:url" />
        <property name="username" value="db2admin" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />

        <!-- Settings -->
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any idea why this happens?

**UPDATE**
I found following options `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` passed as VM arguments. To be honest neither I know how they work nor why they aren't turn on by default. But they seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you spotted which of your classes remain loaded in the application server?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could you tell me how to do this? I have just one class that I create using java code (it's servlet that does nothing). It's seems that .xml files cause this. But hard to say what's stay any tool to determine that?

Comment: are you using aspectJ or something?

Comment: By using a profiler like VisualVM, Java Mission Control, Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) or Yourkit. All of these gives you a great idea about the classes currently loaded in the Java application, then you can pick one of your own classes and analyze why generates a memory leak.

Comment: @Java1 I do not, but hibernate log out that it using javaassist.

Comment: quite possible in your spring application xml, as used for Spring Data (if used) - I think this may cause it.

Comment: @Java1 my application is just empty servlet and above xml's. Because I cannot find leak I start creating file by file testing whether there's leak or not leaks started as soon as those two xml where created. By empty servlet I mean stub generated by eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Try to go back, turn off the flags and force a full GC via VisualVM (installed together with the JDK). You might find that you did not have a memory problem after all, it was just the GC that had not kicked in yet.

**Note:** JDBC drivers should never be installed in the WAR, always on  the server otherwise they cause memory leaks as the driver register itself on a JVM singleton, and upon reload the singleton will refer the driver, that refers the driver class that refers the application previous classloader, causing the pre-redeployment version of the application to not be GC'ed.

I have the impression the flags you mentioned could not have solved the memory leak, see [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/busting-permgen-myths) this quote from the plumbr blogs (memory leak detection tool creators):

> Really, I was unable to find any documentation about these options,
>   except for this page. But, in fact, that does not even matter. In no
>   way any tinkering with the Garbage Collector options will help you in
>   case of a classloder leak. Because, by definition, a memory leak is a
>   situation where GC falls short.

What I think it could have happened is that the while your where doing reloads, the garbage collector was not kicking in yet to collect the previous versions of the application. If without setting those flags you would have forced a garbage collection using for example VisualVM after the reload, the memory should have gone down.

There is no way to control when the garbage collector runs, so there is not guarantee that it will run after an application reload.

If the GC sees that there is still plenty of memory, it will wait until the available memory is lower and run only then, this prevents the application from being penalised by the GC runnning many times without need.

By switching the flags on, you switched on a new type of garbage collector different than the default, that is designed to reduce the length of the GC pauses at the expense of added memory consumption and CPU consumption.

Because this GC enabled by the flags has a different algorithm then the one you used initially, it can decide to run at different times/frequencies. In order to reduce the pauses it will probably run more often. So that would be the reason why you have a memory reduction shortly after reload.

Comment: Well apparently they do. I haven't turn off tomcat machine since time I started question. I'm develop it quite frequently without restart, and all seems fine. Diagrams are stable. No crashesh after hundreds of context reloads
Without those flags I got permgen memory error after like 5-6 reloads. So you can have your scientific approach. I will take mine empiric as believe.